# How to catch a click event on a click to call link in the phone type field in Podio?

Tags: podio

User clicks on a click to call link (href starts with "callto:" or "tel:") in the "Phone" type field in my Podio application. How to catch this event and then add a comment "[Name Surname] clicked to call [phone number]? ([Name Surname] = the user name in Podio, who clicked on the link).

[Phone field click to call link screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xYpO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podio doesn't expose these events to the end-user or clients.